# How to use submenu as filter View?

Tags: views, 8, hooks

I'm new in Drupal 8, and I want to use submenu as a filter in my page.

**Example:**

- ParentChild

  - child0
  - .child1
  - .child2

When I open the Parent Child page I want that submenu appear as a filter.
like this: 
 **child0  child1 child2**  
What should I do??

Comment: When you said filter, did you mean like a drop-down? Or did you mean faceted filtering? Where do you want this filter to appear? In a form in the page? In a view?

Comment: @anoopjohn I mean; that the menu children appear in the view like the taxonomy filter.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of the Summary option of a Contextual filter. You can find Answers here and tutorials on other sites about this, see if this is what you're after.

Comment: @prkos Thank you so much. I will search more.